# How did Sylar take the powers of other evolved humans?

Tags: plot-explanation, heroes

In Heroes, Sylar kills other evolved humans and cuts open their skulls to take their powers. How does he do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

His ability is called [intuitive aptitude](http://heroeswiki.com/Intuitive_aptitude) and basically is an analysis of complex systems, including human brain.

> Intuitive aptitude is the ability to perfectly understand and utilize
>   anything from information, theories, skills, riddles, logic, and
>   puzzles, to the structure and operation of complex systems, codes
>   without special education or training. The user can instantly learn
>   and understand the complexity and exactness of organisms, objects, and
>   even powers.

Sylar is analysing brains of people with abilities and finding out how to copy them:

> Sylar himself describes intuitive aptitude as the ability to
>   understand how things work, and how to fix them if they are broken
>   (Once Upon a Time in Texas). However, the latter aspect of the ability
>   has almost never been utilized by Sylar after his abandonment of his
>   former identity as Gabriel Gray, timepiece restorer.
>
> Sylar's ability seems to work for analyzing mechanical and biological
>   systems.
>
> Sylar does not need to kill someone to gain their ability. However, a
>   physical study of the victim's brain requires direct observation
>   necessitating the removal of the upper part of the skull, so the
>   victim soon dies of blood loss and trauma. Victims with rapid cellular
>   regeneration, however, can survive this by repairing the damage (The
>   Second Coming). Sylar has demonstrated that can also "empathically"
>   copy abilities without injuring the source, but still prefers the
>   brain removal method out of a love of killing. He first demonstrated
>   this by empathically copying electric manipulation from Elle.

Comment: He reads their minds... Literally.

Comment: Yup... reads 'em they're braille. :)